# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is working on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emresaracoglu/dxqzmfb4/#&togetherjs=L0duySkptv) but It does not work on my script also, I get this error with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)

Where is my mistake?

> TypeError: `document.getElementById(...) is null`

```
document.getElementById("image").onclick = function() {
  if (this.src == "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FoXm.png?s=48&g=1") {
    this.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoD62.jpg?s=32&g=1";
  } else {
    this.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FoXm.png?s=48&g=1";
  }
};
```

Comment: Maybe you're running the code before DOM is ready?

Comment: To elaborate on what Bartosz said, if your script appears before the HTML for your image, then it won't work. Try moving the script to the very bottom of your HTML, right before the closing </body> tag, if it isn't there already.

Comment: @BartoszGościński Absolutely! Its working

Answer (score 1):

I added before `</body>` DOM and working. 
[@Bartosz Gościński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2337927/bartosz-go%C5%9Bci%C5%84ski) - I solved the problem with his idea

Answer (score 0):

You have added the line `document.getElementById("image3").onclick = function() {` twice in your code and the second time the name is `imag3e` instead of `image3` which is not present in the DOM and it could be the reason you are getting the error. Remove the unnecessary line and try the following code.

```
document.getElementById("image").onclick = function() {
  if (this.src == "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FoXm.png?s=48&g=1") {
    this.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoD62.jpg?s=32&g=1";
  } else {
    this.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FoXm.png?s=48&g=1";
  }
};
```

Comment: `image` I fixed my question

Comment: The line `document.getElementById("image").onclick = function() {` is still included twice. Remove one of them and run the code